# Generate and print a PDF with specific size in Android

Tags: android, pdf, android-print-framework

I'm working in an Android application, and I want to generate and print a PDF. But I'm having some trouble. I need to generate the `PDF` with 80mm of `width`, and the `height` may vary.

I'm trying this:

```
public class PDFGenerator implements Runnable {
    private Context ctx;
    private View view;
    private Intent mShareIntent;
    private OutputStream os;

    public PDFGenerator(Context ctx, View view) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.view = view;
        makeAndSharePDF();
    }

    public void makeAndSharePDF() {
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public void run() {
        PrintAttributes printAttrs = new PrintAttributes.Builder().
                setColorMode(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_MONOCHROME).
                setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_C7).
                setResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("zooey", ctx.PRINT_SERVICE, 500, 500)).
                setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS).
                build();

        PdfDocument document = new PrintedPdfDocument(ctx, printAttrs);
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new  PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), 1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
        view.draw(page.getCanvas());
        document.finishPage(page);

        try {
            File pdfDirPath = new File(ctx.getFilesDir(), "pdfs");
            pdfDirPath.mkdirs();
            File file = new File(pdfDirPath, "danfe.pdf");
            Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ctx, "br.com.rdscodes.nfcelular", file);
            os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            document.writeTo(os);
            document.close();
            os.close();
            shareDocument(contentUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error generating file", e);
        }
    }

    private void shareDocument(Uri uri) {
        mShareIntent = new Intent();
        mShareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        mShareIntent.setType("application/pdf");
        mShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "NFC-e");
        mShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        ctx.startActivity(mShareIntent);
    }
}
```

This code generates the `PDF`, but with `letter size`.

I saw in [Android Developers media size documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/PrintAttributes.MediaSize.html) that the "ISO_C7" media size is the size the i almost want, but i can change all the "printAttrs" and nothing changes on the final result of the PDF.

Are there better ways to generate and print a `PDF`?  How can I generate my `PDF` with 80mm of `width`?

This part of the app was made by an old employee.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey did you found any solution for this issue?

Comment: @HardikJoshi did you find any solution? can you help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54870164/convert-html-into-pdf-using-webview-not-display-full-content-with-images

Answer (score 2):

Just so you don't break your head over it, like I did, check out this bug report:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=180405

Considering this bug report, I'd say it's a problem with the android printing interface and you can't really set any defaults using PrintAttributes, well at least not until android N.

If you find/found a workaround, please let me know :)

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit later. However, I have made my custom size with this approach : ( widthMils: 5800, heightMils: 40000). The unit of measurement is:  one thousandth of an inch.

```
private PrintAttributes getDefaultPrintAttrs() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) return null;

    PrintAttributes.MediaSize customSize = new 
    PrintAttributes.MediaSize("COIL", "COIL", 5800,40000);
    customSize.asPortrait();

    return new PrintAttributes.Builder()
            .setMediaSize(customSize)
            .setResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("RESOLUTION_ID", "RESOLUTION_ID", 600, 600))
            .setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS)
            .build();

}
```

Comment: it's not working in my case, do you have any alternate solution? here's my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54870164/convert-html-into-pdf-using-webview-not-display-full-content-with-images

Comment: Hi @RuchaBhattJoshi my sample above was just to create a custom size which isn't supported by default. I just needed a page to print in coil paper. So I dynamically calculated the height in html e passed it passed to android as a parameter. HTMLtoPDF approach haven't all capabilities to make easy control all the details. If you really neeed create it client side with images etc, pay attention in the margins, paddings etc. For images try to put them in android/app/src/main/assets folder. Or create them in base64 approach. In my case i haven't images.

Comment: hi @Cassio thank you for your reply, yeah in my case i think image not loading in webview that's why i couldn't convert into html, i'm trying to resolve it.